# Concatenating a string n times which gives memory error

Tags: python-3.x, string, string-concatenation

So i am trying to implement a function that takes a string and int n as input where n is the first n numbers of the infinite string. This function then returns the number of times "a" occurred in that string. Now the problem i face was "memory error" on the input ("a",10000000000000).
possibly because it took a lot of memory;

```
for i in range(n):

    string=string+string
```

I want to know if there are any other ways of handling string to make the string infinite without abusing the memory.
I am slowly building up my logic around python basics, i am sorry if it is a redundant question.

Any help would be amazing.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Looks like you got hit with the [wheat and chessboard problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheat_and_chessboard_problem). I'm not really clear what you're trying to solve, but this is exponential growth and is just going to massively blow up. Every iteration doubles the string, so 1->2->4->8->16->32.... If you do this 64 times, your string length is 18,446,744,073,709,551,615. If you do it 10000000000000 times.... Please clarify what you're trying to do here, computers have finite memory (unfortunately).

Comment: What do you mean "the infinite string"? Is that a known concept? Do you mean a concatenation of the numbers 1 to n? Do you mean that you want the string parameter to take a string that is of functionally infinite length?

Comment: If you replicate the string `n` times then the number of times `'a'` occurs in that string is simply `n` times the number of times `'a'` occurs in the original string.

Comment: @ggorlen i am trying to increase the length of the string and simultaneously searching for a character. So i was thinking what are the other ways of handling string in regards to concatenation.

Comment: @pfdint assuming that it is infinite string (keeps on duplicating). for e.g string='aba' and in every iteration n times i want to search for the character 'a'. so the logic i had in mind was to search the string 'aba' one by one and removing the characters it searches n number of times.

Answer (score 0):

you are not concatenating `n` times. In each iteration, you are doubling the current string. So the size becomes (`k` is the size of `string`),

```
k + 2k + 4k+2nk = k(1 + 2 + 4 + ... + 2n) = k(2^n - 1)/ (2 - 1) ~ k*2^n = O(2^n)
```

Thats why its very reasonable to get memory out of bounds very quickly.

What you need to do is the following to concatenate a string `n` times:

```
res = ""
for i in range(n):
    res=res+string
```

Comment: oh yeah, now i see my mistake. Helped me a bunch.